# React.createRef() does not work - Function components cannot be given refs

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I have this parent class component

```
class TransferHolder extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.transfer = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>HELLO !</h1>
                <Transfer ref={this.transfer}/>
                <Button onClick={() => {
                    const TransferRef = this.transfer.current;
                    console.log('Selected: ',
                        TransferRef.state.projectForm.users.right)
                }}>
                    Print
                </Button>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TransferHolder);
```

When I visit the page an error is shown automatically that says:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `TransferHolder`.
    in ConnectFunction (at TransferHolder.js:19)
    in div (at TransferHolder.js:17)
    in TransferHolder (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Content (at ContentRoute.js:23)
```

I just want to access the state of the `<Transfer>` Component which is a class based Component. However it is also wrapped in redux connect() so I don't know if that does convert it to a functional one.

Comment: how about wrapping your component `Transfer` by a function component which return `Transfer` with additional props to pass that ref as a property to `Transfer`?

Comment: and try to get state through ref seem to not possible? `ref` represents for the DOM object

Comment: I'm new to react Can you show me the code because I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the code for your component `Transfer` looks like this:

```
const Transfer = props => <p {...props}>Some Transfer component</p>;
```

If you use this component like above as

```
<Transfer ref={this.transfer} />
```

it will fail with the mentioned error message

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

because normal function components can not handle refs by default. To avoid that error, you have to wrap your component in forwardRef:

```
const Transfer = forwardRef((props, ref) => <p {...props} ref={ref}>Some Transfer component</p>;
```

Comment: Why doesn't React automatically forward ref for all function components?

Comment: @ArdeshirIzadi Because it is a good thing to choose for yourself which element to forward the ref to if your component includes more than one element.

Comment: Sorry, I asked my question in a bad way. I mean why does it require us to call React.forwardRef on any function component we need ref for. Why doesn't it do it automatically, so we can just have `ref` as second argument and use it (like passing it to any element we want or imperative handle, etc...)